# Call sql procedure through a shell script and email if error

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, oracle11g

I wish to write a shell script that calls a sql procedure(ultimately run the script through a scheduler) and if the procedure gives an sql error of any kind, send the error as an email which i wish to specify inside the script.
How can I do it?

**EDIT:** Here is what I tried. I cannot figure out how to put the logic that send email only if there is error.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/products/11gr1/db
export ORACLE_SID=CTPP01S1 
MAIL_TO="xxx@yyy.com" 
LOGFILE=./xxx_job.log        
exec 2>&1 > $LOGFILE          
echo " Job run at: `date`......" 
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s '/ as sysdba' <<EOF
set head on; 
set feed on;
set serveroutput on;
set linesize 250;   
set pagesize 1000;
exec schema.proc_name; 
exit
EOF
echo "Job ended at: `date`"
mailx -s "OLBB Extract Results." $MAIL_TO  < $LOGFILE
```

Comment: What have you tried and on which platform are you running the shell script?

Comment: I am running the shell script on unix. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the mail from Oracle then [utl_mail](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10802/u_mail.htm) is your friend. As  @Tony noted you didn't specify your platform, but in Linux there's [mail](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_Mail.htm) and in [Unix](http://www.helpdesk.umd.edu/documents/4/4804/) both of which you can pass the output of your execution to.

In any environment you can execute your SQL in a wrapper such as Python (I'm biased) and [mail](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html) from that.

Comment: Thanks. But I want tosend the email only if there is an error. How can I do that?

Comment: @Kaushik, from the code you've just posted; if there is an exception in your SQL procedure then you can use utl_mail to send the mail by `exception when`. If you're using a wrapper than let the SQL throw the exception and catch it outside. In bash `$?` is, I think, the return code for the previous execution line, put this inside a `if .. fi` and `| mail` if necessary...  Personally I'd use `utl_mail`; it's easier. [This](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm) shows you how to handle Oracle errors.